# How apk mod spoof PackageManager?

Tags: android

I created an app, and this app is everytime modded to get the feature of pro version.
I spend already many hours trying to block these "hacks", for exemple checking if the app is been installed from "com.android.vending" or check the signature to be sure of the integrity and other checks.

These checks have been implemented in Java side but also via JNI in C++. All of this has been bypassed just few days after releasing the new version.

After decompiled  the modded APK, i realised these checks are still present on the app. But for somme reason the values returned inside the app are  incorect. Like `getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName("MyApp")`  still return `com.android.vending` whereas it should be `com.google.android.packageinstaller` , if i check outside the modded app the value for exemple of the `getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName("MyApp")` becomes "normal" like `com.google.android.packageinstaller`.

How is that possible and better how can i block it ?

Comment: You're fighting an adversary with physical access; if they can make modifications to your APK you've already lost.

Comment: Yes the previous versions are lost for sure, but what about the next updates My app is a Client making request on a server. I don't think it's lost but it's true, I'm more and more out of idea specially because I don't understand by witch way they realise these exploits.